# Calculate Variance without using the VAR function in RStudio

Tags: sql, r, rstudio, variance

So I am trying to calculate the Variance in SQL within the RStudio program for my university. This would be a simple task if the program would know the function but I either missed it or I messed up something entirely different.

Basically, we have one list with Houses, the Year they were built and if remodeled (otherwhise same year) with the SalePrice. Some other columns as well but they don't take part in this.

Anyways, this is my latest attempt after trying the VAR() function as well as as.numeric in R where it wouldn't "coerce type S4 to vector of type 'double' or "(list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'"..

```
dbSendQuery(con,"SELECT SalePrice FROM Houses WHERE YearBuilt!=YearRemod - (SELECT AVG(SalePrice) FROM Houses WHERE YearBuilt!=YearRemod) / (SELECT COUNT(SalePrice) FROM Houses WHERE YearBuilt!=YearRemod);")
```

I am aware that my sub-selects won't work like this but maybe someone here can help me figure out how to do it properly.

Maybe someone can even tell me which packages i need to do EVERYTHING in SQL. So far I have installed DBI, dplyr, dbplyr, odbc and RSQLITE.

Thanks in advance and I apologise for my amateur attempt at sub-selecting.

Comment: This is somewhat confusing? You are using rstudio as your IDE but you want to calculate the variance in SQL? Or do you only get the data in SQL and calculate the variance in R? In any case there is something wrong with your data selection because the data is a list and not a vector. Without sample data this is hard to correct.

Comment: My apologies. So we are using RStudio, however we are able to use R as well as SQL (it really seems that they do not exactly know either where this course is going). We have a .csv file with Id/YearBuilt/YearRemod/LiveAreaSF/Bedrooms/YrSold/SalePrice as columns and about 600 rows of data in total. The main issue for me (the way i see the issue at hand) is that RStudio is not familiar with the VAR() function and I am not aware how i would get the SUM of all the values fulfilling the criteria substracted by the mean of the column. The data types collide but I dont know how to fix this sadly..

Comment: @Ar2ias be assured [R has a variance function](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.1/topics/cor). So the question is only why it does not work for you. The workflow should be that you use SQL to select the proper subset of data and R to calculate the variance of the relevant columns like this ```var(data$column)```.

Answer (score 0):

While your question misses basic necessary information and background it seems to me there are basic misconceptions at work.

R and SQL are not interchangeable languages and while the IDE RStudio can interpret SQL it does not do so natively.

I encourage you to read this article about connecting R and SQL:

https://db.rstudio.com/getting-started/database-queries/

Using a notebook you could use SQL code to subset the data and save it as the dataframe "mydataframe":

````
```{sql, connection=con, output.var = "mydataframe"}
SELECT SalePrice FROM Houses WHERE YearBuilt!=YearRemod
\```
````

The use R to analyze the data like this:

```r
var(mydataframe$SalesPrice)
```

Comment: I highly appreciate your input and it is very helpfull. Didn't know about the chunks and all but I do like this a lot more than the DBI method. HOWEVER, what might be the possible reason why my var(dataframe$SalePrice) is huge ? I still can not use the VAR() function from SQL itself (even in an SQL chunk) but now this var-function from R will not do the job either.

Comment: @Ar2rias Without knowing your data I am unable to answer this. You mention the variance is huge, well maybe that is just true? Remember that variance is the square of SD and therefore the scale is squared (e.g. variance of meters is in square meters). Can you use ```dput(head(mydataframe))``` to show sample data?